# Looking for a way to pull specific SMS in Android

Tags: android, smsmanager

I am trying to fetch specific text message from SMS manager.

I would like to fetch all the sms that contains"-" (e.g: vm-adress) or only three digits numbers (something like number will just have 234 or 121) in address.

I tried the following:

```
String value = "address like " + "'%" + "-" + "%'";
cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSuri,new String[] {"*"}, value, null, "date desc");
```

This fetches all messages that contains "-" in the address field. How do I fetch both - or numbers (only three digits e.g 121 or 234?)

Is this possible if so how?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK you need to fetch all SMS and apply your sorter on it to extract specific sms's ( something like regex)

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain: When I can filter the SMS according to the above code. I should be able to filter for getting SMS only for three digits.. if you let me know how do get only three digits that this will solve me issue in regex.

Comment: thats what I said. you'll need to use regex (regular expression) for pattern matching.

Comment: How is the question?